# \thispagestyle has no effect if no page broken(\clearpage, \newpage) is given

Tags: fancyhdr

At a certain position in the article, the page that it belongs, need a special fancy style which I do by `\thispagestyle` from the package `fancyhdr`.

In my example as shown in the MWE below, the page, and only the page where the text "bbb" is in(it's at the second page in this example, but may also at the other page, determined by the length of article), need a `\chead`. However, the content of `\chead` is in fact at the first page, not in the second page as I expect.

I think this is because no page-break is given. But the position of text "bbb" is up to the length of article, so how to deal with this problem?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\fancypagestyle{common}{\chead{I want my header only on the page at which  ``bbb'' is located}}
aaa\par\vspace{80em}
bbb\thispagestyle{common}\par\vspace{80em}
ccc
\end{document}
```

***EDIT:***

To make my intention more clearly, I'd like to give the following modified MWE.

My desire is: all pages should have the same header/footer contents which are defined in `\fancypagestyle{allpages}`, except that the page which "bbb" is in(in this example,it's the second page), has a different header/footer defined by `\fancypagestyle{onlythispage}`.

But the real typeset is far from my intention. I think this is because no page-breaks are given.

As the position of "bbb" is up to the length of article, I can't forsee which page it will be in. So, is there an unvesal method to deal with such kind of problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,}

\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{onlythispage}{\chead{only this page}\cfoot{only this page}}
\fancypagestyle{allpages}{\fancyhf{}\chead{all pages}\cfoot{all pages}}

\pagestyle{allpages}

aaa\par\vspace{80em}
bbb\thispagestyle{onlythispage}\par\vspace{80em}
ccc
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\mark` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{common}{\fancyhf{}\chead{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{common}
\begin{document}

aaa\par\vspace{80em}
bbb\markright{I want my header only on the page at which  ``bbb'' is located}\markright{}\par\vspace{80em}
ccc
\end{document}
```

You can also pass a boolean with the mark command use this in the header. The value of the *first* \markright on the page will win.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{bbbpage}

\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{allpages}{\fancyhf{}%
 \chead{\rightmark\ifbool{bbbpage}{only this page}{all pages}}
 \cfoot{\rightmark\ifbool{bbbpage}{only this page}{all pages}}}

\pagestyle{allpages}

aaa\par\vspace{80em}
bbb\markright{\booltrue{bbbpage}}\markright{\boolfalse{bbbpage}}\par\vspace{80em}
ccc
\end{document}
```

In case you need \markright/\rightmark, e.g. to get some \section
on the headers, you could use your own \marks (but this could break e.g. with twocolumn or multicolumn).

Comment: Besides \chead, there are also \rhead, \lhead, \cfoot...etc. in my article. I edit my question. Would you have a look at it?

Comment: I don't like it very much if questions are extended and changed and so make existing answers invalid. I edited now once, but if you have more questions, ask a new one.

Comment: @lyl The community seems to agree with Ulrike's disliking of edits that invalidate existing answers. See for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3625/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7678/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7869/35864 ... It's free to ask a new question in case you later find out that you actually wanted to ask something slightly different (or more).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're using headers, but that's not really relevant.

The problem is that page breaking is asynchronous: typically TeX reads more that fits in a page before deciding it has to ship out a page. In your case, `\thispagestyle` is seen and processed while TeX has not yet decided to eject page 1.

The command `\thispagestyle` is only reliable if given shortly after a page break, for instance when a new chapter is started, a feature which standard classes use for issuing `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

The only reliable method is to use the `\label`-`\pageref` mechanism. Here I implement the job with the help of `refcount` that provides an expandable version of `\pageref`, namely `\getpagerefnumber`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{refcount,pdftexcmds}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\chead{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\thepage}{\getpagerefnumber{bbb}}=\z@
    I want my header only on the page at which  ``bbb'' is located%
  \else
    Normal header%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

aaa\par\vspace{80em}
bbb\label{bbb}\par\vspace{80em}
ccc

\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `\pdf@strcmp` in order to ensure that any kind of page numbering is supported.

The following supports any number of variant headers. *Please, don't dare to ask for a version without* `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

The alternate headers are collected in a property list, indexed by the labels we want to use. At begin document, this property list is reindexed using the page number corresponding to the reference. Due to this, later appearing labels will take precedence in case two labels for alternate headers happen to fall on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just to make a smaller picture
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{refcount,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelylheaders}{mm}
 {% #1: default header
  % #2: label=alternate header, label=alternate header, ...
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_lylheader_default_tl { #1 }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_lylheader_headers_prop { #2 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_lylheader_headers_prop
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_lylheaders_labels_seq { ##1 }
   }
 }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lylheaders_labels_seq
   {
    \prop_gput:Nxx \g_lylheaders_headers_body_prop
     { \getpagerefnumber{#1} }
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_lylheader_headers_prop { #1 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\lylheaders}{}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NxTF \g_lylheaders_headers_body_prop { \thepage }
   {
    \prop_item:Nx \g_lylheaders_headers_body_prop { \thepage }
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \g_lylheader_default_tl
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_if_in:NnTF { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nxx }

\tl_new:N \g_lylheader_default_tl
\prop_new:N \g_lylheaders_headers_prop
\prop_new:N \g_lylheaders_headers_body_prop
\seq_new:N \g_lylheaders_labels_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\lylheaders}

\definelylheaders{Default header}{
  bbb = This is the header for bbb,
  ccc = This is the header for ccc,
}

\begin{document}

aaa\par\vspace{\dimexpr\textheight-\topskip}
bbb\label{bbb}\par\vspace{\dimexpr\textheight-\topskip}
ccc\label{ccc}\par\vspace{\dimexpr\textheight-\topskip}
ddd

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\z@` equal to zero?

Comment: @Sigur Yes. This usage also terminates the number to be looked for.

Comment: But is it testing if some number is zero? I confess that I didn't follow the idea. Without it I got error *Missing = inserted for \ifnum.* but since you used `\z@`, the error after removing it was expected. No surprise.

Comment: @Sigur `\pdf@strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings given as argument are, after full expansion, equal and a nonzero number otherwise.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense to me. Now I understand. Thanks for attention.

Comment: @egreg Is there a solution without `\makeatletter`?

Comment: @lyl Yes: `\csname pdf@strcmp\endcsname` instead of `\pdf@strcmp` and 0 instead of `\z@`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. Your solution is a good idea. If there is another place where the content of chead need to be updated, the  \chead has to be re-wrotten. I'm chasing a way to solve it completely. My edited questiion above is a idea. And maybe another way is how to restore the original content of chead automatically after the current page(I don't want to repeat writing the original chead again and again). Would you please look at this?